# Web-based app to mimic desktop especially printing

Tags: printing

I'm working on an application for a business client. Currently he has a desktop application which is poor in many respects but which has the benefit of being instantaneous when it comes to generating and printing things like invoices / statements.

I am basing the app on server-side PHP (Codeigniter) and a MySQL db, on the client-side I will use HTML5, CSS3, jQuery and EXTjs.

Now, I can handle data transactions pretty much instantly on the client-side with data storage using Javascript and the delay when processing Ajax queries is not significant.

What I am stuck with is how to generate/create invoices (either PDF or RTF) very quickly and send them to the printer without any intervention by the user - i.e. they could be viewing a screen-based invoice and they should be able to click Print and have it appear at the printer without any need to approve a download or save. The business has to be able to create invoices on demand with their customers forming a queue waiting - so delay is not an option.

Is this possible or - and I hate to ask this because of the learning curve involved - am I going to have to look at Flex / AIR?

Any help/advice would be very helpful.

Thank you and best wishes

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to print pdf/rtf docs in one click. At least I don't know how to do this. One idea is that you could have the entire application in ExtJs or whatever you like, but add a Flex part which will be in charge of printing.